# Change NaN to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

How could I change the NaN text to 0?

Im using a function to show a variable price calculator in a Woocommerce store.

Until some variable are selected Im getting a NaN result, once selected it works fine so I would like to just change the NaN text to zero.

This is the code:

```
// hook this on priority 31, display below add to cart button.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_variation_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_variation_price() {
global $woocommerce, $product;
// setup base html... We are going to rewrite this with the standard selected variation
echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px; display: block;">%s %s</div>',__('Precio Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

        var currency    = currency = ' <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

            function priceformat() {
                var product_total = parseFloat(jQuery('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount').text().replace(/ /g ,'').replace(/€/g ,'').replace(/,/g ,'.')) * parseFloat(jQuery('.qty').val());
                var product_total2 = product_total.toFixed(2);
                var product_total3 = product_total2.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');

                jQuery('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + ' ' + product_total3);
            }

            jQuery('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                priceformat();
            });

            jQuery('body').on('change','.variations select',function(){
                priceformat();              
            });

            priceformat();

        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the variable is NaN and if it is set it to zero.

```
if(isNaN(product_total)){
    product_total = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and turns it to zero, but then when I select the variables the calculator doesnt work, it keep in zero.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is:

```js
product_total = product_total || 0
```

Because `product_total` is `NaN` it will assign it to `0`. Be careful though because `0` is also considered a `falsey` value in this scenario.